# Recursive merge sort not returning a sorted array

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I'm writing 3 methods to implement a recursive merge sort, with restricted number of parameters (no aux, lo, mid, hi). I thought that what I had worked, but it isn't returning a sorted array, though it's running without any compilation errors. I've been fiddling with it for 4 hours and can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong to not be merging an ordered array. I only got very vague input from my TA and was able to fix a few issues I was having, but the method still do not sort the array of items. Any advice is welcomed on what I could be doing wrong here. Thanks!

```
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        //Sort a recursively
        a = mergeSort(a);
    }
    
    /** 
     * 
     * Method recursively splits array into halves until length becomes 1, then
     * Calls merge to merge the split arrays back together.
     * @param a Comparable[] 
     * @return a Comparable[]
     */
    public static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] a) {
        if (a.length <= 1) {
            return a;
        } else {
            //create 1st array for D&C, length = 1/2 a.length
            Comparable[] first = new Comparable[a.length / 2]; 
            
            //create 2nd array for D&C, length = a.length - first.length
            Comparable[] second = new Comparable[a.length - first.length]; 
            
            //source/position: a[0], destination/position: first[0], length: first.length
            System.arraycopy(a, 0, first, 0, first.length);      
            
            //source/position: a[first.length], destination/pos: second[0], length: second.length
            System.arraycopy(a, first.length, second, 0, second.length);  
            
            //recursively sort the first half
            first = mergeSort(first);
            
            //recursively sort second half
            second = mergeSort(second);
            
            //merge the halves
            a = merge(first, second);
        }
        
        //return the merged array
        return a;
    }
    
    public static Comparable[] merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] b) {
        Comparable[] result = new Comparable[a.length + b.length];
        
        //Index Position in first array - starting with first element
        int first = 0;
         
        //Index Position in second array - starting with first element
        int second = 0;
         
        //Index Position in merged array - starting with first position
        int merged = 0;
         
        //Compare first and second, 
        while (first < a.length && second < b.length) {
            if (a[first].compareTo(b[second]) < 0) {
                result[merged++] = a[first++];
            } else {
                result[merged++] = b[second++];
            }
        }
        
        //Store remaining elements of 1st array
        while (first < a.length) {
            result[merged++] = a[first++];
        }
        
        //Store remaining elements of second array
        while (second < b.length) {
            result[merged++] = b[second++];
        }
        
        //copy elements from both halves - each half will have the sorted elements
        // System.arraycopy(a, first, result, merged, a.length - first);
        // System.arraycopy(b, second, result, merged, b.length - second);
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize that Java is pass-by-value, i.e. reassigning a parameter is not visible to the caller? So `a = mergeSort(a);` might not have the effect you expect it to have.

Comment: I've removed this previously and it is still running without sorting, but in the code I'm working with now I've removed that and it still is not sorting anything.

Comment: Well, removing that piece of code isn't meant to fix the issue since you're missing a piece in the first place. You need to _return_ the sorted array somewhere to be able to see the changes.

Comment: I was able to implement it correctly with creating a new object within my method to fix the referencing issue that was happening to keep the sorted array from returning to main

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas indicated, Java functions are pass-by-value. So, doing `a = mergeSort(a)` won't change the original array, it will instead sort a copy of it which was passed to function. Instead, you can return the result:

```
public static Comperable[] sort(Comparable[] a) {
        //Sort a recursively
        return mergeSort(a);
}
```

This will calculate everything with local values and return it to original "owner".

Comment: The only issue here is that sort has a void type. So I can't return mergesort, I can only run it and from there implement the recursion inside of mergesort. I know that the issue is happening somewhere within mergesort or merge, but I'm just not sure exactly where.

Comment: Also, I have removed the a = mergesort(a) and placed just mergesort(a) which still does not return the sorted array.

Comment: The problem is not in `a = mergesort(a)`, the problem is in `not return`ing it. Your code sorts the copy of an array, but the original stays UNTOUCHED. The only way to change the original is to RETURN sorted array (which works, I checked that too), which I showed in the answer.

Comment: I've considered that issue as well but the thing is I don't have the option to make sort(Comparable[] a) return a value. The sort method MUST remain void, I can only have mergesort and merge return an array. So I'm not sure how to implement this while staying within the bounds of the assignment.

Comment: How would you go about using a void method that calls the recursive helper, while still returning the value to a? After talking to my instructor I'm aware that the problem is with not returning anything in the method call to a, but I can't figure out how to manipulate the value of a.

Comment: Is it allowed to have a global variable? You can assigned sorted local array to global one

Answer (score 0):

The static method `sort(Comparable[] a)` does not modify its array argument in place. Assigning the result of `mergeSort(a)` only modifies the local variable `a`. You should copy this result back into the array pointed to by the argument `a`:

```
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        //Sort a recursively
        Comparable[] b = mergeSort(a);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 0, a.length);
    }
```